# How to set datasource of a datalist in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I have a datalist. I have datatable in javascript. I want to set datatable as datasource to datalist in javascript.

Is it possible? Can anybody help?

Comment: Why don't you set the datasource in VB?

Comment: I had set datasource in vb.I am changing images in datalist in javascript using webservice.After that i want to reload values from database.I want to do that without postback.i.e why i asked solution in js.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You have to bind your list to a data source using the DataSourceId in the markup or by setting the DataSource attribute in the code behind file. (There might be other solutions, but they are all server side.)

You might be able to solve your problem using the data grid from YUI. This is a JavaScript framework, so it's quite different from ASP.NET.